Facebook login: "URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings."
Trying to log in with Facebook using the below code.
code
I get the following error:
URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.
Error
In the advanced tab, Valid OAuth redirect URIs is set to:
https://smarteresto.com/facebookpost/callback
More settings
App key and secret are correct. Facebook SDK for PHP (v5)

Please do not post code as images. Simply [edit] and copy/paste the code into your question and format it as code.

"In the advanced tab, Valid OAuth redirect URIs is set to: https://smarteresto.com/facebookpost/callback" - but that is not the URL yur code is actually using, you have an additional GET parameter named config_id. If you only have a couple of possible config ID values, then you can specify all of those different URLs in your app settings; if not, then you need to transport the value via the state parameter - that is the only one you can specify freely, without it being part of your registered valid redirect URIs.

(The actual purpose of the state parameter is CRSF protection - if you don't want to disable that, you could pass f.e. a JSON structure, containing your config ID, and a random value, that can then still be validated against the session.)
